# RJS : Retrieve the value of a text_field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, rjs, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using Rails 2.3 and I don't know how to retrieve the value of a text_field of a form in order to handle it in the rjs file. I searched on the Internet all day and I didn't find a solution.

Here is my code to be more specific :

In my form.erb file :

```
<%= observe_field 'issue_'+@issue.id.to_s+'_estimated_hours',
  :url=>{:action => 'check_estimated_hours_field'},
  :with => "'number=' + escape(value) + 
        '&fields_estimated_ids=#{@fields_estimated_ids}'" 
%>
```

Controller :

```
def check_estimated_hours_field
    @fields_estimated_ids = params[:fields_estimated_ids]
end
```

check_estimated_hours_field.rjs :

```
for @field_id in @fields_estimated_ids
     # here I want to add all the values of fields and retrieve the result in a ruby variable 
end
```

**How can I manage to solve the problem I encounter in the comment in check_estimated_hours_field.rjs ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tests and research, it is apparently impossible to recover the value of a form field with RJS.
The solution I found is to create a string containing all fields values ​​in the observe_field and parse this string to the RJS to retrieve the values ​​like this:

In my form.erb file :

```
<% = observe_field 'issue_' + @issue.id.to_s +'_estimated_hours'
  : url => {: action => 'check_estimated_hours_field'},
  : with => "'number =' + escape (value) +
    '& fields_estimated_values ​​=' + $ ('my_form'). select ('[class ~ = estimated_hours]'). collect (function (n) {
       return n.value + '_';
    }) + "
%>
```

In the controller:

```
def check_estimated_hours_field
  estimated_hours_values ​​= params [:estimated_hours_values​​].split('_')
  @total_estimated_hours = 0
  estimated_hours_values.each {| value |
    @total_estimated_hours += hours.to_f
  }
end
```

In this way I can add all the values ​​and retrieve them in the variable @total_estimated_hours